# Quick Sort is Seg Faulting

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, quicksort

Can someone please give me some direction as to why this is seg faulting? I implemented this from a computer science book and I'm not great at debugging recursion. I just don't know where to start to debug.

```
template<class ItemType>
void sortFirstMiddleLast(ItemType arr, unsigned int first, unsigned int mid, unsigned int last)
{
    if (arr[first] > arr[mid]) { swap(arr[first], arr[mid]); }
    if (arr[mid] > arr[last]) { swap(arr[mid], arr[last]); }
    if (arr[first] > arr[mid]) { swap(arr[first], arr[mid]); }
}

template<class ItemType>
int partition(ItemType* arr, unsigned int first, unsigned int last)
{
    unsigned int mid = first + (last - first) / 2;
    sortFirstMiddleLast(arr, first, mid, last);
    swap(arr[mid], arr[last - 1]);
    unsigned int pivotIndex = last - 1;
    ItemType pivot = arr[pivotIndex];

    unsigned int indexFromLeft = first + 1;
    unsigned int indexFromRight = last - 2;
    cout << indexFromLeft << endl;
    cout << indexFromRight << endl;

    bool sorted = false;

    while (!sorted)
    {
        while (arr[indexFromLeft] < pivot) { indexFromLeft += 1; }
        while (arr[indexFromRight] > pivot) { indexFromRight -= 1; }

        if (indexFromLeft < indexFromRight)
        {
            swap(arr[indexFromLeft], arr[indexFromRight]);
            indexFromLeft += 1;
            indexFromRight -= 1;
        }
        else { sorted = true; }
    }

    swap(arr[pivotIndex], arr[indexFromLeft]);
    pivotIndex = indexFromLeft;

    return pivotIndex;
}

template<class ItemType>
void quickSort(ItemType* arr, unsigned int first, unsigned int last)
{
    // Create the partition: S1 | pivotIndex | S2
    int pivotIndex = partition(arr, first, last);

    // Sort subarrays S1 and S2
    quickSort(arr, first, pivotIndex - 1);
    quickSort(arr, pivotIndex + 1, last);
} // end quickSort

int main()
{
    string* a = new string[27];
    a[0] = "B";
    a[1] = "Z";
    a[2] = "Y";
    a[3] = "X";
    a[4] = "W";
    a[5] = "V";
    a[6] = "U";
    a[7] = "T";
    a[8] = "S";
    a[9] = "R";
    a[10] = "Q";
    a[11] = "P";
    a[12] = "O";
    a[13] = "N";
    a[14] = "M";
    a[15] = "L";
    a[16] = "K";
    a[17] = "J";
    a[18] = "I";
    a[19] = "H";
    a[20] = "G";
    a[21] = "F";
    a[22] = "E";
    a[23] = "D";
    a[24] = "C";
    a[25] = "B";
    a[26] = "A";
    quickSort(a, 0, 26);
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: You're excellent if you can determine this program is supposed to work just on sight alone.  Seriously, run your program under a debugger...

Comment: Anything having to to with `[last]` isn't going to bode well when your `last` is 27 and your array is only indexible from 0..26. Right out of the gate you run your median-of-three swap routine which can write to `arr[last]`, which is passed-as-given to the caller as 27, thereby invoking undefined behavior. And I would not be at-all surprised if that wasn't the only place this happens; I just stopped looking once I saw that.

Comment: Fair enough @PaulMcKenzie. Edited.

Comment: @WillLuce What is `string`?  I'm assuming it's `std::string`.

Comment: @WhozCraig I edited it to pass in last as 26. Still a seg fault, but thanks for the input. I would have stopped looking there too. I've been messing with this for a while now and I'm just looking for more sets of eyes.

Comment: @WillLuce - What compiler are you using?  I'm using Visual Studio 2013, and there is a clear warning that the `quickSort` template function is an endless recursion.

Comment: I started in XCode, then went to Geany in Linux. Neither gave me anything to go on. Just seg fault.

Comment: I disagree., Will. I just pummeled this through Xcode, and it showed me one problem immediately: hint: what is stopping `indexFromRight` from *underflowing*?

Comment: @WillLuce - It looks like you're accessing `array[27]` in your `sortFirstMiddleLast` function.  That's out of bounds.

Comment: @WillLuce - This is the warning from VS 2013: `warning C4717: 'quickSort<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >' : recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow`

Comment: Ok, I can see that happening. Let me work through it. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have base cases in your recursion. If your code hadn't crashed while doing the actual work, at least it would be trapped in infinite recursion.

The principle of recursion is that you gradually reduce your problem to smaller problems until you arrive at a trivial problem that you can solve without recursion: The base case. In your case that would be, when the length of your sub-array to sort is less or equal than 3. In this case you can trivially sort the sub-array by just calling your "sortFirstMiddleLast" function.

Particularly, your segmentation fault comes from "indexFromRight = last - 2" becoming negatives, provoking an underflow. That's because your logic doesn't work any longer, when the sub-array to sort becomes to small. But, as stated before: No need for it to work, just implement those trivial cases without the partitioning and recursion.